# How to use TAB Key to focus one of two qpushbutton

Tags: qt, qpushbutton

In a widget I put two QPushButton (let's say "OK" at left and "EXIT" at right).
They regularly work when I press them using the mouse.
Suppose I want to switch from one to the other using TAB key: is it possible?
And how can do this?

Comment: Doesn't it work automagically?

Comment: @Lol4t0 It's platform-dependent.

Answer (score 5):

On some platforms, keyboard focus navigation among buttons is a default behavior, but on some it isn't.

If you wish keyboard navigation on all platforms, the buttons should have a `Qt::StrongFocus` policy set on them. Note that the shortcut used to trigger the buttons is also platform-specific. E.g. on OS X you'd use <kbd>Space</kbd>.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QWidget w;
   QVBoxLayout layout{&w};
   // Individual Buttons
   QPushButton p1{"button1"}, p2{"button2"};
   for (auto p : {&p1, &p2}) {
      layout.addWidget(p);
      p->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
   }
   // A button box
   QDialogButtonBox box;
   for (auto text : {"button3", "button4"})
      box.addButton(text, QDialogButtonBox::NoRole)->setFocusPolicy(Qt::StrongFocus);
   layout.addWidget(&box);

   w.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried it out on KDE/Ubuntu. It works automatically.

## main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.hpp"

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    QApplication app(argc, args);

    MainWindow m;
    m.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

## mainwindow.hpp

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_HPP
#define MAINWINDOW_HPP

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_HPP
```

## mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.hpp"

#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

MainWindow::MainWindow() : QMainWindow() {

    auto* w = new QWidget;
    auto* l = new QVBoxLayout;

    auto* p1 = new QPushButton("ok");
    auto* p2 = new QPushButton("exit");

    l->addWidget(p1);
    l->addWidget(p2);

    w->setLayout(l);
    setCentralWidget(w);
}
```

## a.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = a
INCLUDEPATH += .

QT += widgets

HEADERS += mainwindow.hpp
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++14
```

Edit: Apparently the buttons switch focus, but pressing enter does nothing. I guess you have to use focus-related mechanics (search for "focus" in the [QWidget documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html)) and implement it yourself. Or have a look at [QDialog](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialog.html) (as a replacement for QMainWindow in my example). It should have some meaningful default behavior for the enter and escape buttons.

Side note: Maybe you rather want to use the [QDialogButtonBox](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdialogbuttonbox.html) for ok- and exit-buttons in your project. It's the cross-platform way of displaying OK/Cancel/Accept/Reject/... buttons because their arrangement differs between platforms. And this class can help you with that.

Comment: Your code would be simpler had you used a `QWidget` or a `QDialog` as the top-level widget instead of a `QMainWindow`. The `QMainWindow` is to be used when you need its docking window features. Otherwise, its use is a misguided, with the blame going squarely to the Qt Widget Application template bundled with Qt Creator. If you wish a simple template for concise samples, [I've got one for you](https://github.com/KubaO/stackoverflown/tree/master/qtcreator-templates) :) For a dialog, use a `QDialog` base. For an MDI area w/o dock areas, use a `QMDIArea` directly.

Answer (score 2):

It is easier than all that code. Just use setFocusPolicy with Tabfocus on both buttons like this:

```
 yourButtonOk->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
 yourButtonExit->setFocusPolicy(Qt::TabFocus);
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for. Now, next step is: how can understand what button is focused, so when I press "enter" key, next action corresponds to the selected button ? Is there some "bool" properties to detect this?

Comment: @LittleSaints yes, class QPushButton has a `hasFocus()` property, so you should check it to see if it has the focus or not :). You have too 2 methods: `focusInEvent()` and `focusOutEvent()` which could interest you